# How to split string and put each line in element array in Dart?

Tags: dart

I want to split some string and to contain each line in separate element in array. I use this code for reaching my goal:

```
List _masForUsing;
_masForUsing = new List(numberOfLines);

    void gpsHelper(String text, int count){
        for(int i =0; i<count;i++){
          _masForUsing[i] = text.split("\\r?\\n");
        }
        print(_masForUsing[2]);
      }
```

But when I am truying to evoke the third element of array, it just show full my string. Please help, me :)

> This is example of String:
>
> ```
> real time: 23-09-2019, 23:08:55, Mon 
> system time: 5362 
> gps coordinates: 55.376538; 037.431973; 
> gps satellites: 3; 
> gps time: 20:09:02; 
> gps date: 23.09.19;
> temperature: 19 *C 
> humidity: 35 %  
> dust: 1 
> zivert: 21
> ```

Comment: Your `split` argument is a string, but you are expecting it to be a regular expression. It doesn't match because your string does not contain the five-letter substring "BACKSLASH r QUESTIONMARK BACKSLASH n". To use it as a RegExp, you have to write `text.split(RegExp("\\r?\\n"))` (or, more readable: `text.split(RegExp(r"\r?\n"))` using a raw string). Or use the available `StringSplitter` as recommended below.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use Dart's built in `LineSplitter`, It is system independent.

```
void gpsHelper(String text) {
   LineSplitter ls = new LineSplitter();
   List<String> _masForUsing = ls.convert(text);

    //print(_masForUsing[2]); // gps coordinates: 55.376538; 037.431973;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Is this what you want?

```
void gpsHelper(String text) {
  List _masForUsing = text.split("\n");//this one here

  print('third string is ${_masForUsing[2]}');
}
```

Comment: I added example, which i want to split